# knockout html binding with another binding inside

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using knockout to dynamically loading content into parts of the page, using the HTML binding.

the problem is that the html I want to bind has to do call a function onclick and I need the information about the target and the data that knockout easily send.

something like this:

```
myFunction($parent, $data)
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows" >
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="html: rowValue">this will be a link</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Later I set the value to be a link with a knockout binding inside:

```
rowValue("<a href='#' data-bind=click:alert('hello')" + result.Data + "</a>");
```

Please check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/QfLxM/11/) to see the full working code.

You can see the difference between the 2 lines I wrote, if I do a javascript onclick it works, but obviously ko is missing a late binding.

I've seen many questions about this but can't find one with a definitive answer.

I want to do this with KO, how can this be accomplished? 
with templates maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KO applies bindings when you call ko.applyBindings.
So if you modify the dom after applyBindings has been called. KO won't be aware of the new dom element.

You can use template this way :

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: sitesTable.rows" >
        <tr data-bind="foreach: row">
            <td data-bind="template: 'myTemplate' "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br/>


<a href="#" onclick="getNewData()"> click here </a>
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
    <a href='#' data-bind="html: cellValue, click: openAlert"> click </a>
</script>
```

edit by Maurizio. Use this fiddle as the other linkseems to be broken:
[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/QfLxM/13/)

Comment: thanks for the template conversion of my code. should a template accomplish what I need or not? because your fiddle is not doing it. I modified it to work, but still the data-bind in the template seems to be getting ignored

Comment: actually I managed to fix your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MaurizioPiccini/QfLxM/13/ if you can update your code I will accept your answer for others to see.

Comment: I am glad to hear this was helping.